# How to enable HTTPS SSL with Let's Encrypt Cert working on all ports?

Tags: nginx, ssl, nuxt.js, lets-encrypt

I have a clean Ubuntu VPS, Nginx, Certbot and Nodejs installed on it. I also generated Let's Encrypt Cert in auto mode for mo domain. All configs are very basic, nothing changed as of yet. Now when I go to https://my-site.domain the default nginx page opens and shows that connection encrypted. Then I deployed my Nuxt app (host changed to 0.0.0.0 of course) and tried to connect on port 3000. It says that connection is NOT encrypted and gives error when trying to connect over HTTPS (ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR). When I used HestiaCP as a control panel I didn't have that issue. So, what is the way to use SSL certificate on ALL ports?

Comment: HTTPS is port 443, not 3000.

Comment: Yes, but I also want that all of the ports worked with https. I used to have that when I used Control Panel for setting up certificate. For example, my HestiaCP was on port 8888 and it worked with https with no problems as well as the main domain and all other ports also did. Now I use plain ubuntu server.